# Flutter, Sending Form Data to Email

Tags: flutter

I would like to create a contact form and would like to know: How to send data from a contact form to my email?
I would like to see a working example.
I wanted to submit a form like this:

```
    return new Scaffold(
  appBar: new AppBar(
    title: new Text(widget.title),
    actions: <Widget>[
      new IconButton(icon: const Icon(Icons.save), onPressed: () {})
    ],
  ),
  body: new Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      new ListTile(
        leading: const Icon(Icons.person),
        title: new TextField(
          decoration: new InputDecoration(
            hintText: "Name",
          ),
        ),
      ),
      new ListTile(
        leading: const Icon(Icons.phone),
        title: new TextField(
          decoration: new InputDecoration(
            hintText: "Phone",
          ),
        ),
      ),
      new ListTile(
        leading: const Icon(Icons.email),
        title: new TextField(
          decoration: new InputDecoration(
            hintText: "Email",
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 32):

You can navigate to `default Email app`. You can also set the following attributes from your flutter app.

1. `to mail ID`,
2. `subject` and
3. `body`

using `url_launcher` plugin.

**`Steps:`**

1. Add this to your package's pubspec.yaml file:
   ***`url_launcher: "^3.0.1"`***
2. **`main.dart`** file

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MaterialApp(home: new MyApp(), debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,));

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => new _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: new Center(
        child: new RaisedButton(onPressed: () => _launchURL('xxx@gmail.com', 'Flutter Email Test', 'Hello Flutter'), child: new Text('Send mail'),),
      ),
    );
  }

  _launchURL(String toMailId, String subject, String body) async {
    var url = 'mailto:$toMailId?subject=$subject&body=$body';
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(url);
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $url';
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but what I wanted was to be able to send the data of a form with several fields like:

Name, phone, email, date and time.
I want users to use the form and I want to receive the data by email.

Comment: use string concate ani make a single string.

Comment: Thank you so much, so simple solution...

Answer (score 7):

Try [flutter_email_sender](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_email_sender) package. Here is an example taken from their [github](https://github.com/sidlatau/flutter_email_sender).

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_email_sender/flutter_email_sender.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  String attachment;

  final _recipientController = TextEditingController(
    text: 'example@example.com',
  );

  final _subjectController = TextEditingController(text: 'The subject');

  final _bodyController = TextEditingController(
    text: 'Mail body.',
  );

  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  Future<void> send() async {
    final Email email = Email(
      body: _bodyController.text,
      subject: _subjectController.text,
      recipients: [_recipientController.text],
      attachmentPath: attachment,
    );

    String platformResponse;

    try {
      await FlutterEmailSender.send(email);
      platformResponse = 'success';
    } catch (error) {
      platformResponse = error.toString();
    }

    if (!mounted) return;

    _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(SnackBar(
      content: Text(platformResponse),
    ));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Widget imagePath = Text(attachment ?? '');

    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(primaryColor: Colors.red),
      home: Scaffold(
        key: _scaffoldKey,
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Plugin example app'),
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              onPressed: send,
              icon: Icon(Icons.send),
            )
          ],
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Center(
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: TextField(
                      controller: _recipientController,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        labelText: 'Recipient',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: TextField(
                      controller: _subjectController,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        labelText: 'Subject',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: TextField(
                      controller: _bodyController,
                      maxLines: 10,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          labelText: 'Body', border: OutlineInputBorder()),
                    ),
                  ),
                  imagePath,
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
          icon: Icon(Icons.camera),
          label: Text('Add Image'),
          onPressed: _openImagePicker,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _openImagePicker() async {
    File pick = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    setState(() {
      attachment = pick.path;
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: This seems very useful since it also has an attachment option. I will probably need to attach a photo later to the mail. Thanks!

Comment: @EggBender Nothing happens on click of button...how to resolve this?

Comment: is there a way to check if the email was Sent / Canceled?

Comment: @nani sorry I don't know. check the docs and examples/threads on github, you can also raise a support issue as well

Comment: @nani did you found an answer ? about canceld and sent

Comment: @Merym yeah, on iOS there is a delegate method called didSend or something like that, you can write the code in Native(swift) and call the method via channels in flutter, but i am not sure how to do that in android. We dropped this functionality so i didn't put more work into it.

Answer (score 5):

Please check "mailer" package from flutter. It will use smtp to send email from background without opening userinterface app. It has gmail, yahoo mail, mailgun options to send email.

Reference link :

https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/mailer

Answer (score 5):

If you wanna send it silence and without pop-up any email dialog, you may consider the way which using firebase extension and an [SMTP provider](https://www.sendinblue.com/).

For my example, I'm using Firebase as our backend API, so we choose an extension of Firebase called "[trigger email](https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/firestore-send-email)" to send emails silently.

After you set up an SMTP provider and decided to choose the "Firebase trigger email extension", you can send emails through the form you made in Flutter code silently.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Do you happen to have a concrete example of this? Thanks in advance!