# Send contact form data to email address using flutter and dart

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am building a flutter App and it has a contact form. After filling the contact form, I will like the data provided by the user to be sent to my Email Address (or an email address that I will provide) from the contact form when the user presses on submit without a third party. My form has predefined fields which will be field by the user. Upon submission, I want the forms to be sent to admin's email address. **I AM NOT TALKING ABOUT SENDING A MAIL WITHIN MY APP**

I have gone through the attached question asked here which seems similar but it does not answer my question. I have tried to use url_launcher package but that does not help also.

[Flutter, Sending Form Data to Email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50622947/flutter-sending-form-data-to-email)

**Below is a screenshot of my form.**

[image]

**Below is an excerpt of my code **

```
return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Color(0xFF56ccf2),
  body: SafeArea(
      top: false,
      bottom: false,
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                    top: 10.0, bottom: 5.0, left: 15.0, right: 15.0),
                child: Card(
                  elevation: 6,
                  child: Form(
                      key: _formKey,
                      autovalidate: _autoValidate,
                      child: ListView(
                        shrinkWrap: true, 
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
                        children: <Widget>[
                          //===> Student Number Text Input starts from here <===
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                          top: 10.0, bottom: 6.0, left: 1.0, right: 1.0),
                            child: TextFormField(
                              autofocus: false,
                              focusNode: myFocusNodeEmail,
                              controller: studentNumberController,
                              keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 16.0,
                                  color: Colors.black),
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                                ),
                                labelText: 'Student Number',
                              ),
                              validator: validateStudentNumber,
                              onSaved: (String val) {
                                _stNumber = val;
                              },
                            ),
                          ),

                          //===> Email Address Text Input starts from here <===
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                top: 1.0, bottom: 6.0, left: 1.0, right: 1.0),
                            child: TextFormField(
                              validator: validateStudentEmailAddress,
                              onSaved: (String val) {
                                _stEmail = val;
                              },
                              controller: studentEmailController,
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                                ),
                                labelText: 'Student Email',
                              ),
                              keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 16.0,
                                  color: Colors.black),
                            ),
                          ),

                          //===> Phone Number Text Input starts from here <===
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                top: 1.0, bottom: 6.0, left: 1.0, right: 1.0),
                            child: TextFormField(
                              validator: validateStudentPhoneNumber,
                              onSaved: (String val) {
                                _stPhone = val;
                              },
                              controller: studentPhoneNumberController,
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                                ),
                                labelText: 'Phone Number',
                              ),
                              keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
                              inputFormatters: [
                                FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                                    RegExp(r'^[()\d -]{1,15}$')),
                              ],
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 16.0,
                                  color: Colors.black),
                            ),
                          ),

                          //===> Drop Down Menu starts from here <===
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 1.0, bottom: 6.0, left: 1.0, right: 1.0),
                            child: FormField(
                              builder: (FormFieldState state) {
                                return InputDecorator(
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                                    ),
                                    labelText: 'Semester',
                                    hintText: ("Semester"),
                                  ),
                                  isEmpty: _semester == '',
                                  child: Padding(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 1.0, right: 130 , ),
                                    child: Container(
                                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                                      child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline( 
                                        child: ButtonTheme(
                                          alignedDropdown: true, 
                                          child: DropdownButton(
                                            value: _semester,
                                            isDense: true,
                                            elevation: 5,
                                            isExpanded: true,
                                            onChanged: (String value) {
                                              setState(() {
                                                _semester = value; 
                                                state.didChange(value);
                                              });
                                            },
                                            items: _semesters.map((String value) {
                                              return DropdownMenuItem(
                                                value: value,  
                                                child: Text(value ?? '',
                                                    textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                                    maxLines: 1,
                                                    softWrap: true,
                                                ),
                                              );
                                            }).toList(),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                );
                              },
                            ),
                          ),

                          //===> Query Text Input starts from here <===
                          TextFormField(
                            validator: validateStudentQuery,
                            onSaved: (String val) {
                              _query = val;
                            },
                            controller: queryController,
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                              ),
                              labelText: 'Your Query',
                            ),
                            keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 16.0,
                                color: Colors.black),
                            maxLines: 3,
                          ),

                          Container(
                              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 6.0, bottom: 5),
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
                                boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
                                  BoxShadow(
                                    color:  Color(0xFF008ECC),
                                    offset: Offset(0.0, 0.0),
                                    //blurRadius: 20.0,
                                  ),
                                  BoxShadow(
                                    color:  Color(0xFF008ECC),
                                    offset: Offset(0.0, 0.0),
                                    //blurRadius: 20.0,
                                  ),
                                ],
                                gradient: LinearGradient(
                                    colors: [
                                      Color(0xFF008ECC), //Colors is Olympic blue
                                      Color(0xFF008ECC),
                                    ],
                                    begin: FractionalOffset(0.2, 0.2),
                                    end: FractionalOffset(1.0, 1.0),
                                    stops: [0.0, 1.0],
                                    tileMode: TileMode.clamp),
                              ),
                              child: MaterialButton(
                                onPressed: validateAndSubmit,
                                child: Padding(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                      vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 65.0),
                                  child: Text(
                                    "Submit",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      fontSize: 25.0,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              )),
                        ],
                      )),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      )),
);
```

Comment: You will need to clarify what do you mean by "I will like the data to be sent to my Email Address", do you want to: a) Open default mail app via intent; b) Send email directly from your app via SMTP; c) Something else (please elaborate). Oh btw: a) and b) are covered in the linked question you've posted, you just have to scroll down a bit.

Comment: What I wanted was after the user filling the form, I want the data to be sent to my email address straight. @Uroš

Comment: Then read: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/54161381/5235984](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54161381/5235984)

Comment: No @ChristopherMoore

Answer (score 3):

Well here's a thing. First you need a sender email. `I want the data to be sent to my email address straight.` So by that you mean you don't want the user open it's email app with url_launcher, you need the email to be sent exactly after submitting the form.(Sending email within your app).

With [this](https://pub.dev/packages/mailer) library, you sign in to an email, in your app (obviously your own email, cause you need its password), then you send your data using that email. Now you might say why the heck should I put an email address and it's password in my app! The answer is that it's wrong to send emails within your apps, instead it's better to send these data to a server(which only you can see and edit the code) and then the server sends an email to you using an email library like [this](https://pub.dev/packages/mailer) again, but in server's own programming language.
I suggest you to use firebase functions for doing that, you should write some JS code but you can also find the ready codes on internet too.

Comment: Well you have given me a head-start. I will send the form to firestore and then retrieve it from there. Thanks for your suggestion @Parsa